# Running a haskell program in the repl after changing the file

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghci

I have a haskell program that defines

```hs
module Lib
( someFunc
) where

 

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc  = do
print "Hello world"
```

Opening the REPL with stack loads this lib into the context.

```
*Main Lib Paths_hs> someFunc
"Hello world"
```

After changing the function, writing the file, and executing the function i'm presented with the same result

```hs
someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc  = do
print "Bye bye"
```

```
*Main Lib Paths_hs> someFunc
"Hello world"
```

But i'm expecting the function `someFunc`  to return the new value i've declared `"Bye bye"`.

I've tried running  `stack build` but to no avail.Now, I can re open the REPL, and have the new function, but I don't want to lose my current history. Is there anyway I can load my new compiled program into the current REPL, or load the active sessions history into a new REPL

Comment: I think you're looking for `:r[eload]`. Also see `:help`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#making-changes-and-recompilation), you can use the `:reload` directive (or `:r` shortly).